# What is the Kernel for the KNN regressor in sklearn python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Just wanted to know if anyone knows what the kernel is for the KNN regression in sklearn. I want to use a Gaussian kernel but I'm not sure if the kernel in the KNN regressor is Gaussian, any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about [sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor) here.

It's a little unclear what you mean by 'kernel', but assuming you are talking about how the k neighbours are weighted:

- By default, all K neighbours are weighted equally - a simple mean is taken disregarding the distances of the neighbours (`weights='uniform'`)
- You can set it to weight the neighbours based on the inverse of their distances when taking a mean by setting `weights='distance'` when creating the KNR object.

While a gaussian kernel is not implemented by default, KNR also has support for arbitrary functions which decide weights. You can define one like this:

```
def kernel(distances):
    # distances is an array of size K containing distances of neighbours
    weights = gaussian(distances) # Compute an array of weights however you want
return distances
```

and then passing this to your KNR initialising with `weights=kernel`. I recommend reading the sklearn docs for more info.

Comment: oh i missed that part on the sklearn page, so i'd set the weights equal to a gaussian distribution at the specific point of interest that i'm applying the KNN. so it would look something like this,  exp(-(xi-xq)^2/sigma) where sigma is the standard deviation, xi is the point we're looking at and xq is the neighbor point. Does that make sense? Also how should I set the sigma?

Comment: Sigma is just a parameter you will have to tune. I should point out however in this specific case the distance provided to the kernel is the minkowski distance (this is also configurable). So putting that in your formula, you should just be able to do: `weights = exp(-distances)^2 / sigma`. 

I'm not sure if your formula is correct though (but this is a programming forum not a math theory forum).

Comment: i see thank you very much for the replies, I will try this out!